# Rails 3 model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following models:

User, ProcessType and Remark, as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :process_type
end

class Remark < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :process_type
end

class ProcessType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :remarks
end
```

only some Users are associated with a ProcessType. When a Remark is added, it gets associated with a certain ProcessType (and each ProcessType has a User responsible). I want that when the User associated with a certain ProcessType logs in, to see all Remarks of that processType.

I am not able to figure out the correct approach, maybe someone could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in User.rb, you can have association with remarks directly since user is associated with process_type and process_type is associated with remarks

```
has_many :remarks, :through => :process_type
```

Then to see all remarks you can write this ActiveRecord query

```
current_user.remarks
```

Comment: Thank you! it is starting to make sense now, since I am a beginner in rails and learning.

Comment: please vote up the answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: I don't have the reputation yet, I am new to this site. I will do it with pleasure when I will reach 15 reputation